# How i can use unison to sync. files of folder with the latest modification time?

Tags: unison

I have to handle collisions (someone/something modified both files - How i can  merge changes or just overwrite older version).

In other word I want to sync folders with the latest modification time of its file

Example :- `folder_1/file.txt` changed at **12:30** `folder_2/file.txt` changed at **12:35**

I want to execute `./unison` to give me the following result :- update file with regards to latest modification time so that update file `folder_1/file.txt` to became the same file `folder_2.file.txt`

Comment: i want to sync two folder biased on latest modification time the case [Sooner or later I have to handle collisions (someone/something modified both files - How i can merge changes or just overwrite older version).] is appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the option `-prefer newer`, see also [the unison manual](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html)

Comment: i have another ... when i delete folder from server the unison also delete it from another server but i want to disable delete and enable copy i need always the folder have the same file